# Non-linear equations in Cplex

Tags: cplex, exp, non-linear

I have 2 non-linear equations as below.

How can I present these equations in Cplex?

Thanks in advance.

Q_rsp"=Q_rsp'*(exp(-lamda * t_tht))

deltaQ_rsp=(Q_rsp' - Q_rsp")*y_rsp

with lamda=.25; Q_rsp'=100;

y_rsp: boolean

t_tht: time

Answer (score 0):

For non linear constraints you can use CPOptimizer within CPLEX.

Example https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoononlinear.mod

```
using CP;

// CPOptimizer allows all kind of non linearities

int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
// Non linear objective (exponential) 
minimize
 costBus40*exp(nbBus40) +exp(nbBus30)*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```